# How we can get the public key from pallet id?

Tags: pallet, crowdloan

How we can get the public key of the account generated from PALLET_ID?

```rs
pub const PALLET_ID: PalletId = PalletId(*b"Crowdloa");

pub fn account_id() -> T::AccountId {
    PALLET_ID.into_account_truncating()
}
```

To add the funds to the account, we need public key. How can we get that?

Comment: The returning `T::AccountId` *is the public key*.